# Is there any kind of function or coding that can keep track and count of a number of variables across a stretch of code

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Is there any kind of function or coding that can keep track and count of a number of variables across a stretch of code. For task 2 of Gcse i need to calculate the area of a wall and then times it by 15 for the cost of that 1 wall. Howver the part I am stuck on is how to keep a cumulative count of the total cost of all of the values say if someone had 9 walls for example.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you add your code to the question, it's easier to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I can't understand at all what you are asking about. What is a "kind of coding"? Also there is absolutely no point in having both [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tag. If you do not care about the python version use *only* the [tag:python] tag.  If you have an incomplete solution you should add the code to the question.

Comment: Are you looking for a way in Python to track all variable assignments in memory?

Comment: @Bakuriu it looks like LRobbo9 is just starting stackoverflow as well as python - it take a little time to learn sometimes. There are other questions out there...

Answer (score 0):

```
def calcArea(a,b):
    area = a*b
    return area

def calculateCost(area):
   cost = area * 15
   return cost


num_of_walls = int(input("Enter num of walls"))
cost = 0
for i in range(1, num_of_walls+1):
   dim_a = int(input("Enter a"))
   dim_b = int(input("Enter b"))

   area = calcArea(dim_a, dim_b)
   cost = calculateCost(area)+cost

   print cost
```